# Putting to BI REST server fail

Tags: rest, business-objects

I'm using REST APIs for Web Intelligence and the BI Semantic Layer to generate documents.

1. I manage to get a logon token with [cms]/logon/long
2. I manage to retrieve document parameters with [cms]/raylight/v1/documents/[docId]/parameters
3. But when I put back document parameters with [cms]/raylight/v1/documents/[docId]/parameters, I have this error message:

> System.Net.WebException: Remote server returned an error: (400) Bad request

So:

- Any idea about what is bugging?
- Any idea on how to get more verbose answer? log info?

NB: Nothing interresting or readable in `D:\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\logging`

Answer (score 0):

You can enable tracing to get a more detailed message.

In CMC -> Servers -> WebApplicationContainerServer -> Properties -> RESTful Web Service, check off Show Error Stack, and set the following properties appropriately.

Comment: My server is under Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, what do you mean by CMC?

Comment: CMC is the BusinessObjects admin tool.  By default it's installed at http://server:8080/BOE/CMC.